# Upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6.5 and now no php_oci8.dll

Tags: php, iis

I use `php_oci8.dll` in our application to access an Oracle 8 database server. I upgraded our PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6.5 and now there is no `php_oci8.dll` in the `ext/` folder.

Can I just copy it from the old version?

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php

> The OCI8 1.4 extension is included with PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.5. It is also available from PECL.

Read: *not* incliuded in PHP 5.6 (which is a good thing, not pulling in every single DB interface into the main tree)

Just download that stuff from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8).

You might need to rebuild it from source, though, if whatever Oracle DB client Libraries you use don't match the needs of the OCI8 in its current version

EDIT: Don't do this, OP. Are you really using Oracle 8i? That has seen its last update in 2003 and *should not be used* for security reasons, any more. Seriously, how do you even run this on a modern Operating system? Or do you have a Windows XP machine running as a server exposed to the internet somewhere?!

Comment: The OP may find that their old database can still be accessed via the new binary. But yes, agree with the points that you make - even 10 is old now.

Comment: We use an application (leading in our industry) that ships with a licensed version of Oracle 8. Therefore it's pretty much out of my control what they decide to do or not since it's not our software (we have our own portal written on top of it, hence the question). Do you have links to these "security reasons" that I can send on to them? I guess they might update us then ;-) We use RHEL and it still installs/works fine.

Comment: I *think* kb.cert.org still lists a few open vulnerabilities, but you'd have to read through them just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

**php_oci8.dll** is a very old library used with very old version of Oracle
Now there is a newer version for this library, like **php_oci8_11g** 
The question is : what is the version of Oracle that you use ?

Comment: Why the ?? You asked version I said 8